# Find the general solution for the differential equation $\frac{2x(1-e^y)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx+\frac{e^y}{1+x^2}dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution for the differential equation $$\frac{2x(1-e^y)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx+\frac{e^y}{1+x^2}dy=0$$

I don't understand why the substitution $e^y=t$ is used.
Also, after applying this substitution, the equation is $$t^{'}-\frac{2x}{1+x^2}t=-\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

How to get this form of equation?

Comment: but the equation is separable

Comment: @user_99: The substitution is an attempt so simplify the equation and solve the simplified one and then substitute back when done. After subsituting, we are left with $\dfrac{2x(1-t)}{(1+x^2)^2} + \dfrac{t}{(1+x^2)} = 0$. Multiply by $(1+x^2)$ and simplify to get their form.

Comment: Hi,user-99 a simple way  that is : multiply both sides by $\frac{1+x^2}{1-e^y}$. Then we have a separable equation which can be solved by a simple integration and the final answer is $y=ln(1+c(1+x^2))$